# How do I reformat imported 'addresses' using an Array?

Tags: php, arrays, replace, str-replace

I need a strategy (and help) to accomplish the following;
I import addresses into the DB in this format:

> [ 111 SW 22ND RD, 11111 NE 224TH ST ]

What I need is this:

> [111 SW 22nd Road, 11111 NE 244th Street]

So my objective here is two folds:

1. to lowercase the suffix in the street number [22nd / 144th]
2. to replace the abbreviated street-type with the full word (first letter capitalized), ie.  ST -> Street / RD -> Road

I thought the best way to solve this is to;

1. Lowercase everything first =>  1111 sw 22nd st
2. Then target the 'direction' (sw) back to capitalized, and
3. Finally use an Array within an Array to identify and replace specific text. Ie.
   Way = [way, WAY, wy, WY]
   Street = [street, STREET, st, ST]
   Road = [road, ROAD, rd, RD]

**Is this the best approach?

If so, how do I approach (#2) targeting and capitalizing the 'direction' (SW, NE, etc), and (#3) what is the array that can identify and replace the abbreviated street-type?**

Comment: Don't even try. Three blocks away from my home, there's an "East Road". You cannot reliably mangle street names like you're proposing, because street names are essentially random "garbage" inputs, and the standard delimiters (road, way, etc...) can also be parts of the actual names.

Comment: Yes, I think I recognized that this approach would be out the window if street "NAMES" would were involved.  However, I am targeting a specific community with a specific set of address styles. So I'm wondering does this get solved only if (1) the number of characters are always the same,  or (2) is there a method that will support if the numbered text are different length?  Either way, street NAMES would not be a factor to consider in my case.

Comment: Actually, the first address format complies with USPS address format and naming conventions. The second example does not. What is the reasoning behind wanting to change the format?

Comment: Purely for echo and SEO purposes.  I also believe when people search for an address, they are doing so with the second format.

Answer (score 0):

This took care of it all.  Worked great!

```
<?php
     $data= $row['ADDRESS'];

          $find= array(
               'Way'=> array('WY','WAY','Wy'),
               'Court'=> array('CT') ,
               'Street'=> array(' ST'),
               'th'=> array('TH'),
               'rd'=> array('RD'),
               'nd'=> array('ND'),
               '1st'=> array('1ST')
               );

          foreach($find as $key => $value){
               foreach($value as $r){
               $data= str_replace($r,$key,$data);
                    }
               }
          echo $data;
?>
```

Noy Hadar